# Im trying to change buttons colors on VB.NET

Tags: vb.net

Thats not my code

```
Private Sub SetAllLabelsForeColor(ByVal parent As Control)

        For Each c As Control In parent.Controls
            If TypeOf (c) Is Button And c.BackColor = Color.Red Then
                c.FlatAppearance.MouseOverBackColor = Color.White 'I AM STUCK HERE
            Else
                If c.HasChildren Then
                    SetAllLabelsForeColor(c)
                    Dim b = DirectCast(c, Button)
                    b.FlatAppearance.MouseOverBackColor = Color.White 'I AM STUCK HERE
                End If
            End If
        Next

    End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

are you working with WinForms or WPF?

If you are on WPF then buttons have properties that are defined [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.controls.button?view=windowsdesktop-6.0)

In short, Button is a class part of System.Windows.Controls, to change button background color you need to assign a brush to a background property of that control.

```
Dim myBut as New Button
myBut.Background = New SolidBrush(myColor)
```

If you are working in WinForms:

```
myBut.BackColor = Color.Blue
```

Answer (score 0):

The following uses .NET Framework 4.8, Windows Forms, not WPF the language extension method, in this case obtains all Buttons in Panel1 which also has Panel2 as a child. Some buttons have FlatStyle = FlatStyle.Flat and BackColor = Red while others are standard buttons.

You should add a tag to your post for either WPF or Windows Forms.

[image]

**Extension method**

```
Public Module ControlExtensions
    <Runtime.CompilerServices.Extension>
    Public Iterator Function Descendants(Of T As Class)(control As Control) As IEnumerable(Of T)
        For Each child As Control In control.Controls
            Dim thisControl As T = TryCast(child, T)
            If thisControl IsNot Nothing Then
                Yield thisControl
            End If

            If child.HasChildren Then
                For Each descendant As T In child.Descendants(Of T)()
                    Yield descendant
                Next
            End If
        Next
    End Function

End Module
```

**Form code**

```
Public Class Form1
    Private Sub ChangePropertiesButton_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) _
        Handles ChangePropertiesButton.Click

        Dim Panel1Buttons = Panel1.Descendants(Of Button).Where(
            Function(b) b.FlatStyle = FlatStyle.Flat AndAlso b.BackColor = Color.Red).ToList()

        For Each panel1Button As Button In Panel1Buttons
            panel1Button.FlatAppearance.MouseOverBackColor = Color.White
        Next

        ListBox1.DataSource = Panel1Buttons.Select(Function(button) button.Name).ToList()
    End Sub
End Class
```

Going back to your code, SetAllLabelsForeColor is a bad name for what the method does, even if you copy-n-pasted from somewhere always provide meaningful names to methods and controls.